# Why is the pressure underneath a car splitter lower than the ambient

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, drag, aerodynamics, lift

I seem to get very mixed answers online but i don’t understand why the underside of a splitter is said to have low pressure, i get that the above pressure is higher relative, but not why the underside is low relative to free-stream. Some say it’s because of the Venturi effect, but the cross section area is the same at the ‘lip’ as it is underneath anyway.

And if it is somehow related to the venturi effect, why no angle the splitter upwards on race cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a race car, the front air dam and the splitter are there to push or "sweep" air out from under the car when it is in motion. Pushing the air out from under the car leaves a pocket of lowered pressure underneath the car.

Comment: Nice, ive also seen some cars without an air damn and still have low pressure zone at the tip of the splitter?